# Sigining UWP-Apps with custom code sign certificate

Tags: certificate, xamarin.forms, uwp, codesign, xamarin.uwp

What exactly is the requirement to create a company internal App with Xamarin.Forms UWP? I can compile the *.appxbundle-Package but nobody can install it because of an certificate error. If I try to use our normal code signing certificate from StartSSL to sign the package, I got the following error:

> The Manifest Designer could not import the certificate.
>
> The certificate you selected is not valid for signing because it is
>   either expired or has another issue. For more information, see:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478

The same certificate is used by our other desktop application with the signtool, so I guess the certificate is ok. Usage of the signtool for other .NET assemblies such as WPF projects:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "..\..\..\..\..\Finaltec\Framework\Signing.pfx" /p ... /tr "http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll" "$(TargetPath)"
```

Are there any special requirements to sign a UWP app so anyone can install it? The used certificate is a Class 3 StartSSL Code Signing Certificate and it is valid until Junuary 2020. If I try to install the app with the generated test certificate from the Visual Studio, I got the message that the root certificate is not trusted and the installation process will be canceled. Even if I install the certificate manual before I got the same result error.

**Code Signing Certificate informations:**

- Name: CVA Computer - Visualisierung und Animation GmbH
- Address: Beckebohnen 2
- Zip, City: 31618 Liebenau
- State, Country: Niedersachsen, DE
- Phone: +49-502398110
- Email:  info@cva.de
- Expiry Date: 2017-04-14

**Package.appxmanifest content:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  <Identity Name="f736c883-f105-4d30-a719-4bf328872f5e" Publisher="CN=CVA Computer - Visualisierung und Animation GmbH" Version="1.0.1.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="f736c883-f105-4d30-a719-4bf328872f5e" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>CVA.COS_App</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>CVA Computer - Visualisierung und Animation GmbH</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="FPCL.WIndows.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="CVA.COS_App" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="CVA.COS_App" BackgroundColor="#f4f4f4">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
        <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portraitFlipped" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
        </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

> > If I try to use our normal code signing certificate from StartSSL to sign the package, I got the following error

If we want to sing a UWP app, the **code signing certificate** is needed. The certificate you got from StartSSL is used for client authentication, you can check the **Enhanced Key Usage** field:

**Available code signing cert:**

[image]

**The cert from StartSSL:**

[image]

See also: [What is special about a code signing certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204463/what-is-special-about-a-code-signing-certificate) and [Intro to certificates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/security/certificates)

**------Update 11/16/2016------**

Please see the Validating Certificates section at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478

It looks like this certificate violates the sentence I bolded in:

> Verifies the value of the Enhanced Key Usage property, which must
>   contain Code Signing and may also contain Lifetime Signing. **Any
>   other EKUs are prohibited**.

Their screenshot (below) shows the enhanced keys Codesignatur and **Kernelmodus-Codesignatur**.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The used certificate is a code signing certificate. See this screenshot: https://puu.sh/scrNZ/f01ad0100b.png ("Erweiterte Schlüsselverwendung" means "Enhanced Key Usage" in englisch and "Codesignatur" means "Code Singing")

Comment: @user2050176 I'm ask someone to confirm the details, please pay attention to my response, thank you for your understanding:)

Comment: @Sebastian Please see my updated answer: Update 11/16/2016

Comment: so this means our certificate is prohibited because of the also supportet Kernel mode code signing? Well I guess thats called very bad luck because we can't create a business certificate without the kernel mode singing at StartCom :/